# Fontawsome as a custom marker for the react-google-maps/api component?

Tags: reactjs

is there a way to use FA icon for the marker? I use this code sample:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript } from '@react-google-maps/api';

const containerStyle = {
  width: '400px',
  height: '400px'
};

const center = {
  lat: -3.745,
  lng: -38.523
};

class MyComponents extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LoadScript
        googleMapsApiKey="YOUR_API_KEY"
      >
        <GoogleMap
          mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
          center={center}
          zoom={10}
        >
          <Marker
          position={center}
          icon={'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'}
        />
        </GoogleMap>
      </LoadScript>
    )
  }
}
```

There is the icon property on the Marker component, but it works like an url, like:

```
<Marker position={center} icon={'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'} />
```

I want to use the FA as a custom marker.

```
import { IconName } from "react-icons/fa";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use fortaswome icons for marker.

If want to use `react-icons`, here is how you do that:

```
import { FaBeer } from "react-icons/fa";
     ...

      <Marker
            position={{
              lat: 18.559024,
              lng: -68.388886
            }}
            icon={{
              path: FaBeer().props.children[0].props.d,
              fillColor: "#0000ff",
              fillOpacity: 1,
              strokeWeight: 1,
              strokeColor: "#ffffff",
              scale: 0.075
            }}
          />
```

Other option is to use `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons`.
In that case, code will look something like this:

```
import { faCoffee } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faCoffee";

  ...

       <Marker
            position={{
              lat: 18.559024,
              lng: -68.388886
            }}
            icon={{
              path: faCoffee.icon[4],
              fillColor: "#0000ff",
              fillOpacity: 1,
              strokeWeight: 1,
              strokeColor: "#ffffff",
              scale: 0.075
            }}
          />
```

Source: [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-modern)

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-shaw-6ecub0?file=/src/Map.js)

Comment: Thanks, but it works only with the Fa type icons. I mean the FaBeer works fine, but for example the `import {GiBeerStein} from 'react/icons/gi'` doesn't work sadly. Do you now maybe why doesn't this work?